# Error Message "latex-engine has been removed" when knitting to pdf

Tags: r, pdf, knitr, r-markdown, pandoc

I'm working on a Mac and have an R script file that I would like to compile to a PDF document. I have inserted the following at the top for the output:

```
#'   beamer_presentation:
#'     toc: yes
#'     slide_level: 2
#'     latex_engine: xelatex
```

Once I press command+shift+k to knit this file, I get the following error message:

```
--latex-engine has been removed.  Use --pdf-engine instead.
Try pandoc --help for more information.
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 2
Execution halted
```

I did download mactex and pandoc 2.0.1.1. from the pandoc website. Some of my colleages are able to knit the file, so I'm rather sure that the content is not the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue has been [reported](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/1120) and fixed in the current development version of **rmarkdown**, which you can install with:

```
if (!require("devtools")) install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("rstudio/rmarkdown")
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. As I'm new to R, could you explain to me what I need to do with this code: devtools::install_github("rstudio/rmarkdown")